# Dockerfiles or images in docker hub?

Tags: docker

Why is docker hub keeping images rather than dockerfiles, it would be much lighter, no?

The dockerfile is the recipe for the image after all...

Can you explain that choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that way, you don't have to build them, you can "download" ([`docker pull`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/)) images directly from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/).

Building is not always possible as you need to copy and configure an image with resources which you might not have locally.

Comment: Plus they don't always build the images in official repositories.

Comment: That's relevant indeed. Thanks :)